# Python - Problem with writing file Errno 2

Tags: python

I am a Python newbie and I am having a problem that probably has as a simple answer. I have the following script, which works most of the way, I just get stuck trying the write the output file. The error I get is at the very end: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/D/1_NEW_ANALYSIS/Scripts/Melodic_fsfs/design_Rat01_Run_1.fsf'

Here is the code:

```
import os
import glob

studydir = 'D:/1_NEW_ANALYSIS'

fsfdir="%s/Scripts/Melodic_fsfs"%(studydir)
templatedir="%s/Scripts/Templates"%(studydir)

subdirs=glob.glob("%s/Subjects/Rat_[0-9][0-9]/Run_[0-2]"%(studydir))

for dir in list(subdirs):
  splitdir = dir.split('\\')
  # YOU WILL NEED TO EDIT THIS TO GRAB sub001
  splitdir_sub = splitdir[1]
  subnum=splitdir_sub[-2:]

  splitdir_run = splitdir[2]
  runnum=splitdir_run[-1:]
  print(subnum)

  replacements = {'SUBNUM':subnum, 'RUNNUM':runnum}
  with open("%s/Melodic_design.fsf"%(templatedir)) as infile: 
    with open("%s/design_Rat%s_Run_%s.fsf"%(fsfdir, subnum, runnum), 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile: 
          for src, target in replacements.items():
            line = line.replace(src, target)
          outfile.write(line)
```

Anybody have an idea why it doesn't work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on windows (I assume you are), studydir should look like:

```
studydir = 'D:\\1_NEW_ANALYSIS'
```